# Почему Минспорт склоняется?

Tags: выбор-слов, склонение, сокращения

«Я работаю в МинспортЕ»? Грамота пишет, что слово склоняется... Но это ведь ерунда. «Я работаю в министерствЕ спорта». Расшифровывается слово так. Нет же слова «минспорт» в словаре...

Answer (score 2):

Существуют разные варианты названий  **в начальной форме**, поэтому они могут склоняться или не склоняться.

Название Минпросвещения России не склоняется. При этом склоняются наименования **с усеченной конечной частью**: Минтруд, Минспорт, Минздрав... (но: Минобрнауки, Минобороны – не скл.!)

Вопрос № 286939. Как правильно писать: Минспорт или Минспорта объявляет конкурс?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка. **Официально принятое сокращенное название – Минспорт России.** Поэтому окончание А в им. падеже не нужно.

Вопрос № 273068.  Уважаемая грамота! Склоняется ли Минспорт?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка.
Это слово склоняется: Минспорта, Минспорту, Минспортом, о Минспорте.

Comment: «Минобороны – не скл!»...Министерство обороны расшифровуется...все верно...Почему не может быть минспортА....не понимаю...

Comment: Я полагаю, что сложносокращенные слова выбирают для себя удобную фонетическую форму в индивидуальном порядке. Если слово кончается на твердый согласный звук, его удобно приписать ко 2-му склонению для сущ. м. рода – отсюда Минтруд, Минспорт, Минздрав с усеченной основой (существуют же слова труд, спорт). А вот Миноборон(ы) при усечении выглядит странно,  такую форму нельзя считать начальной формой слова  в И.п. , поэтому  это слово  не склоняется и  в остальных падежах.